# Command tooltip sometimes is missing its keybinding

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, key-bindings

I am about to migrate an E3 (v3.7) application to E4 (v4.7) running in compatibility mode.
Sometimes tooltips do not display shortcuts from their keybindings.
The Keybindings are always working properly when the key is pressed.

Tooltips of commands using default Eclipse contexts, e.g. *org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow*, always show up correctly.

Contexts that are activated at runtime programmatically (a part listener changes contexts by the editor or view activated) do not update their commands' tooltips. 
Except: When clicking into a view or editor with a table viewer and changing or removing the selection, the tooltips are generated with the keybinding again.

But: Applying the same command in different editors (each with an own context) to different keybindings causes them all to display the same keybinding 
of the context that was activated last, and was refreshed due to changing the selection of a table - no matter if the part received a focus.

With E3 the part activation alone updated the keybinding tooltip, while in E4 e.g. a table selection must be changed to refresh the tooltip.

Is that a known issue?
Is there any way to programmatically refresh toolbars/coolbar to display the keybindings of the current context? I know when to refresh, but not how.

Comment: Same here. Can confirm it might be related to the context, since we have a couple of those custom ones getting activated at runtime too. I know, this question is quite old, but I think still relevant. Any news from your side?